# play framework bat windows java process

Tags: windows, playframework

I am having troubles launching a standalone play application as a Java process on Windows.
I use the "play dist" command in order to generate a zip file containing all the jars that are necessary for the application to run.
The zip file also contains the "start" file that contains a script that is supposed to launch the application (works fine on Linux server).

I found the sbtgoodies plugin with the "play dist-unzip" command https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/sbtgoodies. It works fine but I always get a unix script "start". How can I get a windows script "start.bat"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The start.bat with the following command line should work :

```
java %1 -cp "./lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer .
```

Note the ";" after lib/* to prevent Windows preprocessor from expanding the wildcard

Comment: Where do you put this start.bat?

Comment: at the root of the folder generated by dist-unzip. But you can put it wherever you want and adjust "./lib:*;" to point to your lib directory

Comment: This works but stops working when I try and add -D java parameters like "java %1 -Dconfig.file=application-prod.conf -cp "./lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer ."

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your classpath property is different. Have you tried with -cp "staged/*"

Comment: Sorry that was the script generated by "play stage" command and not "play dist".