# Deploying play framework could not find or load main class

Tags: java, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0, windows-7-x64

I'm preparing a deploy using `Dist`command in Windows 7. (play 2.0.4)

The zip is generated successful but when I'm trying to start the application with this command:

```
java -Dhttp.port=9001 -cp "e:\deploy\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT\lib\*" play.core.server.NettyServer
```

The console displays this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   e:\deploy\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT\lib\ch.qos.logback.logback-core-logback-core-1.0.0.jar

I've checked that this jar is generated by Play Framework in... `c:\Play\play-2.0.4\repository\cache\ch.qos.logback\`

If I execute start or run command, the compilation and execution are successful.

Using `stage` command I receive other error:

```
[error] {file:/C:/test/}test/*:stage: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm not sure but would be related with the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic of `;`
In the fist command I added `;` after the `*` 
[this prevent Windows pre-processor from expanding the wildcard.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910236/851009)

Finally:

```
java -Dhttp.port=9001 -cp "e:\deploy\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT\lib\*;" play.core.server.NettyServer
```

I've deployed in other windows system x64 previously and the `;` wasn't necessary.