# Play Framework batch file with command-line flags

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, playframework-2.0

I created a Windows batch file to start my Play Framework application as detailed here: [play framework bat windows java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894615/play-framework-bat-windows-java-process)

```
java %1 -cp "./lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer .
```

This works, but when I try and add a command-line flag to specify a production configuration file I get a 'Not a Play application' error message:

```
java %1 -Dconfig.file=application-prod.conf -cp "./lib/*;" play.core.server.NettyServer .
```

My two questions are:

1. What does the '%1' and '.' represent to the java launcher?
2. How can I pass the '-D' command-line flags to the Play application in a
   Windows batch file?

Comment: the %1 is the first argument the batch-file is called with, four instance if the batch-file is called with `something.bat test` then `%1` will be `test`

Comment: Why does the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894615/play-framework-bat-windows-java-process have a '%1' with no information about what arguments are passed to start.bat.

Comment: does it get called from another program, or does it always need to be called manually?

Comment: We're calling it manually, sounds like it's safe to leave the '%1' off then, just need to figure out how to make the '-D' flags work.

Comment: I wouldn't leave out the %1, I'm guessing (because of it's position) that that's probably the location of the java file that needs to be executed, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through trial and error we arrived at the following solution:

```
java -cp "./lib/*" -Dconfig.file=application-prod.conf play.core.server.NettyServer
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!